# Density of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, banach-algebras

I am interested in operators on non-reflexive Banach space. Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $L(X)$ be the algebra of operators acting on $X$. We may embed $L(X)$ into $L(X^{**})$ by $\Phi(T)=T^{**}$; this is an algebra homomorphism. Is the image $\Phi(L(X))$ dense in $L(X^{**})$ in the sense of the classical operator topologies like WOT, SOT etc when $X$ lacks the approximation property?

EDIT: Now, cross-posted at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111079/density-of-adjoint-operators).